# Set Include object to start at the end of other Include

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a layout with 2 include tags.
I want that the second include will start when the first end.
Thats my xml code:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

<include android:id="@+id/content"
    layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

How can i do that?
Right now they are located at the same position.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Tom, check the proposed solution. It should work in most cases. Otherwise if you have some hidden options or requirements for this layout you could specify them in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positional relationship of these components is determind by their parent layout. So the simplest way to solve your issue is to wrap them into LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

    <include android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

There are also other options of how you can manage your re-usable components [described in the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)